# is reference conversion is the standard conversion

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

c++ standard says standard conversions include

```
 A standard conversion sequence is a sequence of standard conversions in the following order:
(1.1) — Zero or one conversion from the following set: lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, array-to-pointer conversion,
and function-to-pointer conversion.
(1.2) — Zero or one conversion from the following set: integral promotions, floating point promotion, integral
conversions, floating point conversions, floating-integral conversions, pointer conversions, pointer to
member conversions, and boolean conversions.
(1.3) — Zero or one qualification conversion.
```

But it hasn't metioned reference conversion.
Which is used widespreadly in c++; like:

```
auto ex = std::runtime_exception();
std::exception& ref = ex; //reference conversion


//reference to Derived converion to reference to Base in
// operator = call in object slicing
class B{};
class D : public B
{};
B b = d;
```

I don't know why?

Comment: [Reference binding](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.ref)

Comment: @Danh that clause discusses parameter binding in overload resolution, which although related and interesting, is not what the question was about.

Answer (score 1):

See §8.5.3¶4 in the C++11 standard:

> Given types “cv1 T1” and “cv2 T2,” “cv1 T1” is reference-related to “cv2 T2” if T1 is the same type as T2, or T1 is a base class of T2. “cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “cv2 T2” if T1 is reference-related to T2 and cv1 is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, cv2.

In your case, `std::exception` is a base class of `std::runtime_exception`, making `ref` reference-related to `ex`. Since neither `ex` nor `ref` are `const` or `volatile`, they have the same cv-qualification, and `ref` is reference-compatible with `ex`.

§8.5.3¶5:

> A reference to type “cv1 T1” is initialized by an expression of type “cv2 T2” as follows:
>
> — If the reference is an lvalue reference and the initializer expression
>
> — is an lvalue (but is not a bit-field), and “cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “cv2 T2,” (...)

`ref` is an lvalue reference, the initializer expression `ex` is an lvalue, and we already established that `ref` is reference-compatible with `ex`.

Also relevant is the final sentence in §8.5.3¶5

> In [the case I quoted above] the reference is said to bind directly to the initializer expression.